# Static class in class const

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to implement this without using any methods.

Is this possible in any way?

```
class Foo extends Bar{
    const foo = static::class;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll keep hunting.

Comment: I gave you an answer, but it might be helpful if you described what exactly are you trying to achieve - maybe we could find a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Well, I have a system that utilizes inheritance pretty heavily. Kinda just a fun "lets set if we can do it" project. I asked this 16 hours ago, and since then I decided that I was taking the wrong approach in this specific instance. Thanks your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

> initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

`static` is lazy evaluation, and is evaluated only at run-time, thus this is not possible.

Also read about
[late static bindings](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#language.oop5.late-static-bindings.usage)

> > Late static bindings […] references the class that was initially called at **runtime**.

Comment: Const scalar properties should be available in [PHP5.6](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs)

Comment: `static` is not scalar; it is a lazy (run-time) evaluation of `self`.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer. I've decided that the reason that this even was a question I had to ask boils down to bad code design on my part.